# EmberJS with Mirage not fully populating the record

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

I have an Ember model set up with mirage and a serializer. When I added some new fields to the model, they never get populated despite being in the payload:

`serializers/application.js`

```
....
normalizeArrayResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
        const payloadTemp = {};
        const rootKey = Ember.String.pluralize(primaryModelClass.modelName);
    payload.properties.forEach((property, index) => {
    //  in here, property["property_type"] returns the correct value based off 
     ///the fixtures in mirage. Afterwards, property.get("property_type") is  always undefined
            payload.properties[index].featured_image = property["embedded"]["wp:featuredmedia"]
    });
        //payloadTemp[rootKey] = payload;
        return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType);
    },
```

`models/property.js`

```
export default Model.extend({
  date: attr('date'),
  slug: attr('string'),
  title: attr(),
  excerpt: attr(),
  department: attr('string'),
  latitude: attr('string'),
  address_street: attr('string'),
  address_two: attr('string'),
  address_three: attr('string'),
  address_four: attr('string'),
  address_postcode: attr('string'),
  features: attr('string'),
  feature_1: attr('string'), //new
  feature_2: attr('string'), //new
  feature_3: attr('string'), //new
  feature_4: attr('string'),  //new
  longitude: attr('string'),
  price: attr('string'),
  price_formatted: attr('string'),
  currency: attr('string'),
  tenure: attr('string'),
  property_type: attr('string'), //new
  bedrooms: attr('string'),
  bathrooms: attr('string'),
  parking: attr('string'),
  reception_rooms: attr('string'),
  featured_image: attr()
});
```

Example fixture:

```
"id": 20829,
"date": "2017-05-22T16:31:42",
"date_gmt": "2017-05-22T16:31:42",
"guid": {
"rendered": "http://www.example-estates.co.uk/property/goldstone-crescent-dunstable/"
},
"modified": "2017-05-25T16:00:04",
"modified_gmt": "2017-05-25T16:00:04",
"slug": "goldstone-crescent-dunstable",
"status": "publish",
"type": "property",
"link": "http://www.example-estates.co.uk/property/goldstone-crescent-dunstable/",
"title": {
"rendered": "Goldstone 2 Crescent DUNSTABLE"
},
"excerpt": {
"rendered": "<p>NO UPPER CHAIN &#8211; A THREE BEDROOM EXTENDED SEMI DETACHED HOUSE LOCATED TO THE EAST OF TOWN THAT FEATURES, CLOAK/SHOWER ROOM, UTILITY ROOM/STUDY, LANDSCAPED GARDENS AND GARAGE WITH AMPLE PARKING.</p>\n",
"protected": false
},
"template": "",
"department": "residential-sales",
"address_street": "",
"address_two": "",
"address_three": "Dunstable",
"address_four": "",
"address_postcode": "LU5 4QU",
"latitude": "51.8936687",
"longitude": "-0.5047035",
"price": "325000.00",
"price_formatted": "&pound;325,000",
"currency": "",
"price_qualifier": "",
"sale_by": "",
"tenure": "Freehold",
"deposit": "",
"furnished": "",
"available_date": "",
"bedrooms": "3",
"bathrooms": "",
"reception_rooms": "1",
"property_type": "Semi-Detached House",
"parking": "Garage and Driveway, Parking For 2 Cars",
"outside_space": "",
"featured": "",
"availability": "For Sale",
"marketing_flags": "",
"features": [
"NO UPPER CHAIN",
"A THREE BEDROOM EXTENDED",
"SEMI DETACHED HOUSE",
"LOCATED TO THE EAST OF TOWN",
"CLOAK/SHOWER ROOM",
"UTILITY ROOM/STUDY",
"LANDSCAPED GARDENS",
"GARAGE WITH AMPLE PARKING",
"GAS FIRED CENTRAL HEATING",
"DOUBLE GLAZING"
],
"feature_1": "A THREE BEDROOM EXTENDED",
"feature_2": "SEMI DETACHED HOUSE",
"feature_3": "LOCATED TO THE EAST OF TOWN",
"feature_4": "CLOAK/SHOWER ROOM",
"description": "<p class=\"room\">ACCOMMODATION COMPRISES: Etended entrance hall, utility/study, cloak/shower room, large kitchen/dining room, large lounge to the rear of the property overlooking landscaped private garden, large landing with three generous bedrooms and bathroom, driveway, ample parking and gardens.\n                </p>\n                ",
"office": {
"name": "Dunstable Office",
"address": "20 West Street Dunstable Bedfordshire, LU6 1SX",
"telephone_number": "01582 661112",
"email_address": "sales@example-estates.co.uk"
},
```

Within the `normalizeArrayResponse` function, checking for `property.property_type` exists within the `payload.properties.forEach` loop but then once it becomes a record the fields that were added after the model was first created (highlighted with `//new` are always undefined (`property.get('property_type')`, for example).

Comment: if you could include all the related files in ember-twiddle it would be easy to paly around..I made repo with like you mentioned, For me `property.get("property_type") ` it shows `get is not function error` . I doubt there is some hurdle in understanding the problem with the given input.  If you want I would setup twiddle with my files, that will give you idea what is going wrong on your end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your *mirage/serializers/application.js* is using RESTSerializer,

```
import { RestSerializer } from 'ember-cli-mirage';
export default RestSerializer.extend({});
```

So ensure that you are extending `DS.RESTSerializer` in *app/serializers/application.js.*

1. Response data is removing `_` and make it camelCased key. So if you defined `property_type` then mirage is responding it with `propertyType`, in the same way for all the data to align with RESTSerializer format, look at this

```js
console.log({"id":"20829","date":"2017-05-22T16:31:42","dateGmt":"2017-05-22T16:31:42","guid":{"rendered":"http://www.example-estates.co.uk/property/goldstone-crescent-dunstable/"},"modified":"2017-05-25T16:00:04","modifiedGmt":"2017-05-25T16:00:04","slug":"goldstone-crescent-dunstable","status":"publish","type":"property","link":"http://www.example-estates.co.uk/property/goldstone-crescent-dunstable/","title":{"rendered":"Goldstone 2 Crescent DUNSTABLE"},"excerpt":{"rendered":"<p>NO UPPER CHAIN &#8211; A THREE BEDROOM EXTENDED SEMI DETACHED HOUSE LOCATED TO THE EAST OF TOWN THAT FEATURES, CLOAK/SHOWER ROOM, UTILITY ROOM/STUDY, LANDSCAPED GARDENS AND GARAGE WITH AMPLE PARKING.</p>\n","protected":false},"template":"","department":"residential-sales","addressStreet":"","addressTwo":"","addressThree":"Dunstable","addressFour":"","addressPostcode":"LU5 4QU","latitude":"51.8936687","longitude":"-0.5047035","price":"325000.00","priceFormatted":"&pound;325,000","currency":"","priceQualifier":"","saleBy":"","tenure":"Freehold","deposit":"","furnished":"","availableDate":"","bedrooms":"3","bathrooms":"","receptionRooms":"1","propertyType":"Semi-Detached House","parking":"Garage and Driveway, Parking For 2 Cars","outsideSpace":"","featured":"","availability":"For Sale","marketingFlags":"","features":["NO UPPER CHAIN","A THREE BEDROOM EXTENDED","SEMI DETACHED HOUSE","LOCATED TO THE EAST OF TOWN","CLOAK/SHOWER ROOM","UTILITY ROOM/STUDY","LANDSCAPED GARDENS","GARAGE WITH AMPLE PARKING","GAS FIRED CENTRAL HEATING","DOUBLE GLAZING"],"feature1":"A THREE BEDROOM EXTENDED","feature2":"SEMI DETACHED HOUSE","feature3":"LOCATED TO THE EAST OF TOWN","feature4":"CLOAK/SHOWER ROOM","description":"<p class=\"room\">ACCOMMODATION COMPRISES: Etended entrance hall, utility/study, cloak/shower room, large kitchen/dining room, large lounge to the rear of the property overlooking landscaped private garden, large landing with three generous bedrooms and bathroom, driveway, ample parking and gardens.\n                </p>\n                ","office":{"name":"Dunstable Office","address":"20 West Street Dunstable Bedfordshire, LU6 1SX","telephone_number":"01582 661112","email_address":"sales@example-estates.co.uk"}});
```

2. `payload.properties[0].property` is normal Object, its not having `get` method  so `property.get("property_type")` this will show `.get is not function` error.
3. You can directly manipulate `payload` and return it. You don't need to introduce `tempPayload`.

```
    import Ember from 'ember';
    import DS from 'ember-data';    
    export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
        normalizeArrayResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
            payload.properties.forEach((property, index) => {
                property['featured_image '] = "new value";
            });
            return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved this issue before your answer but  you were bang on with the `camelCased` point with this in the mirage application serializer: 
`export default RestSerializer.extend({
  keyForAttribute(attr) {
    return underscore(attr);
  }
});
`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use [`normalize`](https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalize) instead of `normalizeArrayResponse`? I used it to add some properties and it worked fine for me. BTW, are you sure that you need to modify payload in serializer? I suggest to do this only if you don't have control over backend. Otherwise it is better to modify backend to be compatible with ED.

Also, in your code I see that you are trying to assign `featured_image` a value of `property["embedded"]["wp:featuredmedia"]`. But I don't see such property in your fixture. This may lead to fatal error which can interrupt execution of `normalizeArrayResponse` method. I recommend to check browser console for errors and check your fixture.